# Pass Result of Function (Return) as a Prop in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-props

In my application, I am attempting to pass the result of `number()` as a parameter inside a Link. However, it seems like it is attempting to *literally* pass in the whole function (the raw text of the function), rather than the result (which is really stupid, and doesn't make any sense). What am I missing? Is there a better way to do what I am aiming for? Thanks!

**CODE**

```
function number() {
    return 0;
}

<Link to={{pathname: '/path', state: {number: number}}}>Go</Link>
```

Comment: How about you just store the result to a variable before passing it to the component? let myNumber = number();
<Link to={{pathname: '/path', state: {number: myNumber}}}>Go</Link>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the value of the function you have to do the following:

```
<Link to={{pathname: '/path', state: {number: number()}}}>Go</Link>
```

**Edit**:

I was able to do it like I said before.
But in the target component of the Link, the `state` is inside the `props.location`. 
For example, if Link sends to the following Path component, you need to define the `props` argument in the component and access `props.location.state.number` like this:

```
const Path = (props) => (
  <div>
    {props.location.state.number}
  </div>
)
```

You can view an example working in this link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/a-simple-react-router-v4tutorial-9s3f6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: I'm sorry, but this does not work. It also calls `number` over and over again (this is why I didn't do it in the first place).

Comment: @GeorgeB I edited the answer and posted an example working, if it is not working for you, can you post your code?